# Parent process didn't exit while using cd xxx && nohup sh xx.sh &

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I've met this weird issue last night but still have no clue about it. Here's the thing:

I got 2 processes named `parent.sh` and `child.sh`, and it's supposed to be `parent.sh` start the `child.sh`, and then `parent.sh` exits while `child.sh` still run. (`parent.sh` is just like `apachectl` or anything in `/etc/init.d/xxx`

code in `parent.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

echo 'start child.sh'
cd $HOME && nohup sh child.sh &
```

code in `child.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

while true;
do
    echo 'child process';
    sleep 10
done
```

After I run `sh parent.sh`, it seems like the `parent.sh` has exit cause I got the bash. Unfortunately when I do `ps -ef | grep parent.sh` , it's still there with a parent process `init`, and the child process `child.sh` is also running.

After some check for `parent.sh`, I found that if I change this line:

```
cd $HOME && nohup sh child.sh &
```

to

```
cd $HOME; nohup sh child.sh &
```

then the parent process will exit after it start the child process.

Why?

Comment: At a guess the first case the entire complex command is put in the background but only the `child.sh` process is detached from the parent so the shell that ran `cd` is still around until `child.sh` exits. In the second the `cd` happens in the parent shell and then the `nohup` process is detached so nothing is left running in the parent shell context to stick around. But this is all supposition. Does `nohup sh -c "cd $HOME && sh child.sh" &` work correctly? (Also if your scripts are bash scripts then use `bash <script>` and not `sh <script>`.)

Comment: Thanks for reply,  `sh -c` will lose the environment variable `$HOME`.   And, inspired by you I think here is how the `cd $HOME && nohup sh child.sh &` works:   this `&` in this command will let the whole command `cd $HOME && nohup sh child.sh` running in the background,  which is put the `parent.sh` to the background, and because of this I will got a new bash in the terminal. Then because there is no `&` after the `nohup sh child.sh`( the original `$` works for the parent.sh) , so the `nohup sh child.sh` will not exit, so the background.sh will no exit and remain in the background.

Comment: The `$HOME` in that nohup suggestion will be expanded by the *current* shell before being run. Note the double quotes.